# Can someone explain to me the harmonic reasoning behind this chord progression?

Tags: chords

E minor 7 9    G dim 7     D# dim 7 9    E minor 7 9

Let’s just say we’re in the key of E minor

Please I’m so confused

Answer (score 4):

I think we can safely ignore the 9's in all the chords--I don't believe they affect harmonic function here.

G dim 7 is enharmonically equivalent to A♯ dim 7, which is a secondary dominant chord in the context of E minor. Specifically, it's vii°7/V in E minor.

The A♯ dim 7 chord leads to a dominant-function D♯ dim 7 9 chord.

Then we're back to the decorated Em 7 9-chord tonic.

Comment: A# dim 7 is the secondary dominant of what chord? And is the d# borrowed from E major? Thanks for the quick reply :D

Comment: In other words, it’s Em - F#7 - B7 - Em in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-wording from existing answer and comments...

Enharmonically respell `Gdim7` to `A#dim7` as `A# C# E G`

The `D#dim7` is `D# F# A C`

Extend that with the part @piiperi hinted at:

*some theory treats leading tone diminished seventh chords as incomplete dominant ninth chords.*

If we put the supposed root of those incomplete dominant ninths in parenthesis we get these chords: `(F#) A# C# E G` then `(B) D# F# A C` then `Em`, which is straight-forward `Em: V9/V V9 i`